# Java: Unwanted spaces in header space when converting ms word to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, xwpf

I am using below code to convert existing word to PDF. 
But while creating page , second page of generated PDF contains unwanted header space. 
Is it possible remove this space from second page ? In the input file , i have a bigger header in first page  and i  have only a small header in second page.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inputFile = "input word.docx";
    String outputFile = "output.pdf";
    if ((args != null) && (args.length == 2)) {
        inputFile = args[0];
        outputFile = args[1];
    }

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

    File outFile = new File(outputFile);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    PdfOptions options = null;
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

}
```

Dependencies added :

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my second page of input word document looks like
[image]

Here is my output pdf generated currently looks like
[image]

Comment: Where are the versions of maven dependencies defined? What are the versions?

Comment: @Boris Thank you for pointing this out . I have now  modified the dependencies with version.